# RaphaelJS issue ...DRAW or REDRAW?

Tags: raphael

Hi I have a dropdown menu & whenever I change the option in the dropdown I want to change the content in the canvas...For example

```
var paper = Raphael("myDivID",400,400);
function smallRectangle(){
  paper.rect(10,10,100,50);
}
function bigRectangle(){
  paper.rect(10,10,150,100);
}
```

In my dropdown i'll have two options "small rectangle" & "big rectangle". I want to call corresponding functions on dropdown selection. The issue I'm facing with is that once i change the dropdown option Raphael don't seem to draw it. **I have read from some questions in stackoverflow that there is no need to use redraw technique in RaphaelJS** 
[See the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114416/how-to-redraw-raphael-object-after-paper-clear)!

Even If I try this way:

```
var paper = Raphael("myDivID",400,400);
function smallRectangle(){
  paper.clear()
  paper.rect(10,10,100,50);
}
function bigRectangle(){
  paper.clear()
  paper.rect(10,10,150,100);
}
```

This don't seem to add elements to canvas after the `clear()` function. Canvas remains empty. 

***FYI:my code is very large so I posted this simple example here.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to redraw the rect again ....

```
function resize_Rect(rect,newWidth,newHeight){//passing rect ,new width and new height
         rect.attr({'width':newWidth,'height':newHeight});
               }
```

Hope it helps you out ...